# How to revoke installation rights on an account on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, administrator, uninstall

A laptop has Windows 8.1 installed, with all the available updates. This laptop has two accounts: A and B. A (my account) has administrator rights. Is it possible to give B the same administrator rights except the rights to install and uninstall programs, rights which I still want them revoked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make these changes login to the user you want to change the settings of, and make the changes.  There's also ways to do it by a script but I doubt that's the solution you need to bother with.

There's a lot of different rules you can set for users but it's kind of a slippery slope in my view.  I'll try to explain a little bit on it in a sec.  As for actually making the change you want:

Start -> Run -> gpedit.msc

Goto: Computer Configurations > Administrative templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer

Find "Disable Windows Installer" and set that to true.

It might also be under a different name, I think it changes a little bit from OS to OS."Turn off Windows Installer" might do it too.

Here's more info on the subject:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-prevent-users-from-installing-programs-in-windows-7

The reason why this is a slippery slope is because policies can be changed by users unless you go through and block that from happening.  A curious person will almost always find a way around your changes but if that's not something you're too worried about, go for it.  I don't think the average user will find ways around this stuff but ya never know I guess.

Comment: This might actually prevent you (the default admin) from making these changes.  Meaning it might make the policy system wide.  This may mean that you might need to make a script and apply it to the user you want it done on.  It's been years since I've done this stuff and have never done it in Windows 8.  But maybe this will at least get your foot in the door to figure out the right solution if the above doesn't work how you want.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your answer!